# How to select random rows whose column sum meets the condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, random

Is it possible to select random rows from a table whose particular column total (sum) should be less than my condition value ?

My table structure is like -

```
id | question | answerInSec
1  | Quest1   | 15
2  | Quest2   | 20
3  | Quest3   | 10
4  | Quest4   | 15
5  | Quest5   | 10
6  | Quest6   | 15
7  | Quest7   | 20
```

I want to get those **random** questions whose total **sum** of 'answerInSec' column is less than (nearest total) or equal to 60.

So random combination can be [1,2,3,4] OR [2,3,5,7] OR [4,5,6,7] etc.

Is this possible in single MySQL query ?

Comment: Any possible solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you look for this :

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY RAND() WHERE [condition] LIMIT 10
```

Comment: No, i want to get those random questions whose sum of 'answerInSec' column less than 60